# Android - AlertDialog inside Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, adapter

I'm workin' on an android native app and I'm havin' some troubles with the `altert dialog` inside my `adapter`.
The main `activity` contains a `fragment`, which in turn contains a `recyclerView` with which an `adapter` is associated.
The `recyclerView` contains several elements and in each of them there is a button that allows to trigger an alert dialog. When the content insertion process is carried out and afterwards, the error "Unable to add window - token null is not valid; is your activity running?" Appears. and the alert dialog (code) does not appear.

**My adapter code:**

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.state.setOnClickListener {
        if (result_info_feridas!!.result!![position].isClosed == true.toString()) {
            alertDialogConfirmProcess("abrir", position, holder.state, context)
        } else {
            alertDialogConfirmProcess("fechar", position, holder.state, context)
        }
    }

}
```

**My Alert dialog:**

```
private fun alertDialogConfirmProcess(state: String?, position: Int, stateButton: Button, context: Context) {
    var response: Boolean?
    val alertDialog =  AlertDialog.Builder(view.rootView.context)

    if (state == "fechar") {
        alertDialog.setMessage(view.rootView.context.resources.getString(R.string.confirm_close_wound))
    } else {
        alertDialog.setMessage(view.rootView.context.resources.getString(R.string.confirm_open_wound))
    }

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(view.rootView.context.resources.getString(R.string.sim)) { dialog, which ->
        stateButton.isClickable = false

        response = if (state == "fechar") {
            closeWound(result_info_feridas!!.result!![position].intervention!![0].woundId, ObjectToken.accessToken).closeWoundRequest()
        } else {
            openWound(result_info_feridas!!.result!![position].intervention!![0].woundId, ObjectToken.accessToken).openWoundRequest()
        }

        if (response == true) {
            if (state == "fechar") {
                alertDialogResponseState(view.rootView.context.resources.getString(R.string.photo_closed_success))
            } else {
                alertDialogResponseState(view.rootView.context.resources.getString(R.string.photo_opened_success))
            }

            if (seeClosedWounds == true) {
                updateResultWoundsInfo(result_info_feridas!!.result!![position].patientId!!, "All")
            } else {
                updateResultWoundsInfo(result_info_feridas!!.result!![position].patientId!!, "Opened")
            }
        } else {
            stateButton.isClickable = true
            alertDialogResponseState(view.rootView.context.resources.getString(R.string.erro))
        }

        dialog!!.dismiss()

    }

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton(view.rootView.context.resources.getString(R.string.nao)) { dialog, which ->
        dialog!!.dismiss()
    }
    stateButton.isClickable = true
 /*   val dialog = alertDialog.create();*/
    alertDialog.show()
}
```

Comment: I would use the activity context in your dialog instead of view.rootView.context (in fact, you are passing the context as a parameter but then you're not using it). That might be one of the causes.

Comment: If i use that context give me this error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pt.f3m.rita.mpds/pt.f3m.rita.mpds.Activities.InfoPatient.Utente}: java.lang.NullPointerException" and it never works

Answer (score 0):

```
val alertDialog =  AlertDialog.Builder(context)
```

Comment: If i use that context give me this error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pt.f3m.rita.mpds/pt.f3m.rita.mpds.Activities.InfoPatient.Utente}: java.lang.NullPointerException" and it never works

Comment: Try using getActivity() instead of context.

Comment: private Context context;

public Adapter( Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

Comment: u need to pass the context to the adapter

Comment: do that in your activity
adapter = new Adapter( getContext());

Comment: If you're adding to your answer, please edit your answer, don't add it as comments.

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated parts of your code which is creating dialog and it actually appeared, which got me thinking that you are passing AlertDialog.Builder Constructor some kind of invalid context which is very weird. could you maybe show me whole code and what do you set as view global variable?

Comment: It appears but if we insert or remove items, the button no longer works.